# Stringstream read values into double fails?

Tags: c++, stringstream

**New Problem**

`boost::tokenizer<> token(line);` tokenizes decimal points! How can I stop this happening?

**Previous problem below is now resolved.**

I am trying to grab values from a stringstream into a vector of doubles.

```
std::ifstream filestream;
filestream.open("data.data");
if(filestream.is_open()){
    filestream.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);

    std::string line;
    std::vector<double> particle_state;
    particle_state.resize(6);
    while(filestream >> line){

        boost::tokenizer<> token(line);

        int i = -1;
        for(boost::tokenizer<>::iterator it=token.begin(); it!=token.end(); ++it){
            std::cout << *it << std::endl; // This prints the correct values from the file.

            if(i == -1){
                // Ommitted code
            }

            else{
                std::stringstream ss(*it);
                ss >> particle_state.at(i); // Offending code here?
            }
            i ++;
        }
        turbovector3 iPos(particle_state.at(0), particle_state.at(1), particle_state.at(2));
        turbovector3 iVel(particle_state.at(3), particle_state.at(4), particle_state.at(5));
        // AT THIS POINT: cout produces "(0,0,0)"
        std::cout << "ADDING: P=" << iPos << " V=" << iVel << std::endl;

    }


    filestream.close();
}
```

Contents of input file:

```
electron(0,0,0,0,0,0);
proton(1,0,0,0,0,0);
proton(0,1,0,0,0,0);
```

More on turbovector3:

`turbovector3` is a mathematical vector class. (The important thing is that it works - essentially it is a vector with 3 items. It is initialised using the constructor with three doubles.)

Thanks in advance for help!

**EDIT** Modification of code:

```
std::stringstream ss(*it);
if(ss.fail()){
  std::cout << "FAIL!!!" << std::endl; // never happens
}
else{
  std::cout << ss.str() << std::endl; // correct value pops out
}
double me;
ss >> me;
std::cout << "double:" << me << std::endl; // correct value pops out again
particle_state.at(i) = me; // This doesn't work - why?
```

Comment: I can't actually see anything wrong with this code.

Answer (score 1):

Do you increment `i` in the omitted code? If not your `else` clause never gets called. Try outputting the `stringstream` buffer contents:

```
  std::cerr << ss.str();
```

Also check if reading from `ss` actually fails:

```
  if (ss.fail())
      std::cerr << "Error reading from string stream\n";
```

Comment: `i++` is called inside of the if statement. I will update this.

Comment: Only other thing I can think of is somehow assignment to the vector element reference fails. Try `particle_state.at(i) = 12;  std::cerr << particle_state.at(i);`. If that gives the right thing, I'm all out of ideas.

Comment: For some reason `ss >> me` does not work if the file has something like `-1.0` instead of `1`. I will try the thing you just said above.

Answer (score 0):

Solution! I fluked and found this site: [Link](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lib.boost.devel/58386)

The solution is to change the tokenizer to this:

```
boost::char_delimiters_separator<char> sep(false,"(),;");
boost::tokenizer<> token(line,sep);
```

Now it works!